# NSTextField value is not updated immediately after model changes

Tags: nsuserdefaults, cocoa-bindings

[image]

I bind the textfield with a key in `NSUserDefaults` and the "Chose File..." button modifies the model.

But the textfield is not updated after the button get clicked. I have to re-open the window to see the new value been populated into the textfield.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because my key has a dot "." in it which confused data binding.

It was:

`[ defaults setValue: xxx forKey:@"proxy.url"]`

It should be:

`[ defaults setValue: xxx forKey:@"proxy_url"]`